# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Netbeans 7.0

Tags: netbeans7.0

Hi you can call me Kenshi. I am a highschool student trying to take a online programming class. I would ask my teacher but she almost wrecked my laptop beyond repair because she knows nothing about this. here is my problem.... A few weeks ago i typed up a program finding the surfacearea of a cube. And ever since then when ever i try and run a program it runs the cube program instead. I deleted the project and when i did i got the Java.lan.NoClassDefFoundError. I have heard that i have to delete the Cashe of the program, i had to wipe my computer (due to my teacher) and that didnt work. I followed the program instructions on the Fundamentals of Java Textbook. And when i re typed the program once i got my laptop back and running I still go the error. If you can help it would make This one Very Happy. Below i will provide the whole error code.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: studentapps/StudentApps (wrong name: StudentApps/StudentApps)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
```

Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Again Much appreciated!!

EDIT: This is the code of the Class its self.

```
package StudentApps;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentApps {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Student student1 = new Student();
Student student2 = new Student();
Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

String name;
int score;

System.out.print("Enter the first students Name: ");
name = reader.nextLine();
student1.setName(name);
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter the student's Score");
    score = reader.nextInt();
    student1.setScore(i, score);
    }
reader.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter the second students name: ");
name = reader.nextLine();
student2.setName(name);
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter the student's Score");
    score = reader.nextInt();
    student2.setScore(i, score);
    }
System.out.println(student1);
System.out.println(student2);

if (student1.getHighScore() > student2.getHighScore()){
    name = student1.getName();

    score = student1.getHighScore();
}else{
    name = student2.getName();
    score = student2.getHighScore();
}
System.out.println(name + " has the highest score: " + score);

if (student1.getAverage() > student2.getAverage()){
    name = student1.getName();
    score = student1.getHighScore();
}else{
    name = student2.getName();
    score = student2.getAverage();
}
System.out.println(name + " has the highest average score: " + score);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without actually seeing your code. But notice the first line:

```
studentapps/StudentApps (wrong name: StudentApps/StudentApps
```

There is `studentapps` and also `StudentApps` in first parts before the slash '/'. Don't you have somewhere this typo?

Comment: When i made the project it minimized the name when i had it look just like the class. I typed it up exactly as the text book says. it has another class that would run with it. and the build is fine for it. the whole code will be added after this post.

Comment: I Fixed the typo. and it RUNNED!! THANK YOU FOR SHOWING THAT.... wish i noticed it.... Any Way Thanks!!